# How to remove rootkits and malware?

Tags: malware, rootkits

I have downloaded and ran the programme Rootkit Hunter and the results are worrying.

I don't know much about malware other than a malicious individual has persistently been installing it onto my machines via malicious emails - this time targeting my iPhone 4 (which I promptly got rid of upon discovering this individual's presence and replaced with a new Samsung S4, which is probably infected as well now) first; and from there using my house Wifi network to get onto my Macbook Pro 10.8.3 (which is the machine I am on now, and the machine the results refer to); and also my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1; and most likely the phones and computers belonging to other members of my family are compromised as well.

The following are the worrying results identified by Rootkit Hunter:

For "Checking LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable", it says in yellow "skipped".

For "Checking for hidden processes", it also says in yellow "skipped".

I also have red warning notices in relation to system configuration file checks and filesystem checks alerting me to the following:

> "Checking if SSH protocol v1 in allowed The SSH configuration option
>   'Protocol' has not been set";
>
> "Checking if syslog remote logging is allowed Syslog configuration
>   file allows remote logging: install.* .0.1:32376"
>
> "Checking /dev for suspicious file types Suspicious file types found
>   in /dev: /dev/fd/6: MS Windows icon resource"
>
> "Checking for hidden files and directories Hidden file found:
>   /usr/share/man/man5/. rhosts.5: troff or preprocessor input text".

I do not know how to interpret these results other than of course realising they are alerting me to the fact that something is wrong and needs fixing.

I do not know exactly what Rootkit Hunter is telling me is wrong, and I do not know how to fix the problems it has identified.

I would greatly appreciate it if anybody could perhaps tell me how I can do these things. And any advice on which programmes to use for my Samsung machines and the best way to protect my devices in the future would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It costs too much time to find out where some root kits may be hidden. You wanted to install a new version to a new, bigger disk anyway for some time.

Comment: I'm not sure how to install to a "bigger disk". I have tried reinstalling both Mountain Lion and the Android operating System, and this definitely does not remove the malware - although theses are not quite "clean" reinstallations; I'm not quite sure to do those. It is equally important also that I prevent it from happening again, and I am most interested in knowing how to protect machines from other ones; because hacking into one machine on any given network seems to pretty much guarantee access to all the machines on it for someone that is determined to do it.

Comment: I have external hard drives. Is it easy to reinstall onto those? And what about phones? My external hard drives are Samsung and even getting photos onto them from my Macbook is a bit tricky.

Comment: The keyword in my comment was `new`. Don't do just an OS upgrade.